# Current state of the existence of absolute space debate

Tags: cosmology, space, relativity

Samir Okasha writes about the controversy concerning the existence of absolute space in [Philosophy of Science: A Very Short Introduction](http://books.google.de/books?id=W2jCrzKYqxMC&lpg=PP1&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) (2002):

> One of the intriguing things about the absolute/relational controversy
>   is that it refuses to go away. Newton’s account of space was
>   intimately bound up with his physics, and Leibniz’s views were a
>   direct reaction to Newton’s. So one might think that the advances in
>   physics since the 17th century would have resolved the issue by now.
>   But this has not happened. Although it was once widely held that
>   Einstein’s theory of relativity had decided the issue in favour of
>   Leibniz, this view has increasingly come under attack in recent years.
>   More than 300 years after the original Newton/Leibniz debate, the
>   controversy rages on.

Unfortunately this is the last paragraph in the chapter about this topic... which is a little bit frustrating.

So my question is:
What is the current state of the debate (this was written more than 10 years ago)? Is it still not settled and what are the main strands and results of research on that topic?

Comment: What is the question? Whether space exists?

Comment: @jinawee: Whether *absolute* space exists.

Comment: @V.Moretti: The source is about (post-)relativistic physics so I don't understand your comment?!?

Comment: Why the downvote and the vote to close? It is good practice here give some reasons and feeback how to improve the question! Thank you

Comment: @V.Moretti: Marginal or not: Is it settled? What is the final result then?

Comment: Since this is a philosophical question I don't think it can be settle at all. Even less by physics. May be you can ask how physicists think about space-time, relational or not, or something along that line. But then it still may not be suitable here.

Comment: @MBN: No, it is *not* a philosophical question! Either space *is* absolute or it is *not*. Only because the quote is from a philosophy book?!?

Comment: What is absolute space?

Comment: @V.Moretti: I am afraid I cannot follow. I am talking about the fabric of space and you say that this is *a matter of personal taste* - sorry but completely discombobulated now...

Comment: @V.Moretti: Could you perhaps craft an answer out of your comment: "It depends on the meaning of "absolute space" you consider. As far as we know, at large scales [...]" - This sounds interesting!

Comment: The debate is still active. See, for example
http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/9055/
and references therein.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about philosophic interpretations of space-time and not physics. Perhaps http://philosophy.stackexchange.com might be better suited for this question.

Comment: @KyleKanos: I am repeating myself:  No, it is not a philosophical question! Either space is absolute or it is not. Only because the quote is from a philosophy book does not make it a philosophical question!

Comment: @vonjd: I thought you were asking whether space-time is relational or not, and that is a philosophical question. You keep repeat that you are asking if space is absolute. Well, then it is not, end of story.

Comment: @MBN: Argumentum ab auctoritate or what?

Comment: @vonjd: What is your question about, absolute space or the nature of space-time?!!!

Comment: @MBN: From alanf's linked article (I couldn't have said it better): "Strictly speaking, the controversy has concerned two candidate entities. Prior to Minkowski’s
reformulation of Einstein’s special theory of relativity in four-dimensional form, the debate was
about the existence of space. Since then, the debate has been about the existence of spacetime. For
the sake of brevity, I will often only mention spacetime, leaving the “and/or space” implicit." This is why in the abstract of the article it says: "spacetime *and its parts*"

Comment: It's a philosophical question because only philosophers are arguing over the state of space.

Comment: While I feel like it might not get answered properly on PhilosophySE, this is a philosophical question because it has only to do with humans arguing over the interpretation of "what space is", or what the exact meaning of "absolute" even is.